# Graph API empty events list of page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

currently I'm trying to access the events list of a facebook page. I used the Graph API Explorer with a valid access token.

```
Endpoint: {page-id}/events
```

When I'm trying to access the end point the response is empty

```
Endpoint: matrixberlin/events for example returns

{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I don't understand why I got an empty respones because the events are public and even visible for non registered users. Do I need some extra permissions for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here. It seems to be related to facebook´s changed regarding their privacy issue. There are some breaking changes and apps need a review. More infos here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes